# Druid in earth elemental shape and melded into a wall

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

A druid which is wild-shaped (elemental body) into an earth elemental has the ability "earth glide". I have a couple of questions regarding this:

- If he's inside of a wall, can he see/hear what's happening in an adjacent room?
- Can he cast (while he's inside of the wall) into an adjacent room?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there are rules explicitly for this, but I have a suggestion.

Compare [Earth Glide (Ex)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Earth-Glide-Ex-) to [Incorporeal (Ex)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Incorporeal-Ex-) and borrow some of the "pass through solid objects" restrictions.

> - Don't need to remain adjacent to the object's exterior — Earth Glide is clear on this point.
> - Can sense creatures directly adjacent.
> - In order to see beyond the object it is in and attack normally, the creature must emerge.

Unless the druid has other senses, Earth Glide doesn't let him sense any more than he normally would and being embedded in a wall is somewhat limiting.  Likewise, he doesn't have any line of effect to anything (other than the wall or himself) while in the wall.

Comment: Agreed.  I'd let the druid sense anyone touching the wall or very close, and let them maybe hear noises/speech with a slight Perception penalty, but not see things or cast (even blindly).

Comment: What does exactly mean "... the creature must emerge."? Can he emerge, cast a spell and then go back inside the wall?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 8):

I'd use the rules from [Meld Into Stone](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/meldIntoStone.htm). You can't see, but you can hear (sound travels through solids). You can cast spells, but only on yourself. It's a nice way to get a break, heal yourself, charge up *poison* or *rusting grasp*, and so forth.